# How to manually reload IOptions in ASP.NET Core RC2 application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have asp.net Core Rc2 application. To store system setting I use IOptions mechanism which is configured like that:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<DocumentParameters>, DocumentParametersConfigureOptions>();
```

All parameters are loaded from database in DocumentParametersConfigureOption class. Thanks to this solution, all system settings can be easily injected into controllers/services and are cached on the server side (they are loaded only at the start of application).

I have also a page where settings can be modified (modified in database). I would like to know how can I reload them when user clicks save without restarting web application service.

Comment: The easiest that I can think of is to change your `AddSingleton` to `AddScoped`. But this means you would hit the database once for every request which you probably want to avoid. The issue is with knowing when to reload the settings when the change happens. Also note that you do NOT want to change the singleton instance of your options when the webpage changes as it could cause some requests to be dirty state(where some settings are read before your change but some after)

Comment: Instead of loading all settings on startup I would consider lazy loading them on first access and then caching them so subsequent requests won't go to the database.  When you modify the settings you need to simply clear the cache and then the next access request for the settings will re-populate them from the database.  It may be worth looking into the `IMemoryCache` service that can be injected by using `services.AddMemoryCache()` in your `Startup` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in [memory caching](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/memory.html).

On load, put your configuration there. On conclusive connections/resolves, read it from there. When you update it via UI, simply invalidate the cache (i.e. using the cancellation token, see link from above) or just put it manually back in there overriding the existing value.

Comment: I think i will try with this In memory caching thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second set of `IOptions` and inject them with either `AddTransient` or `AddScoped`.

Transient services will be created every time they are requested, and scoped services will be created once per request.

[Here's a link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) to documentation on service lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

on asp.net core 1.1 you can achieve this with [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot)